# Suppress output for a2ensite and a2dissite commands

Tags: apache2

I've been trying to find a way to suppress the output for the **a2ensite** and **a2dissite** commands. Man pages don't seem to provide for any sort of "silent" or "quiet" mode.

Here's what I see with **a2ensite**:

```
Enabling site...
Enabling site HELLO.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
```

And with **a2dissite**:

```
removing dangling symlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite
```

Is there any way to prevent any output at all ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried `> dev/null` before but it didn't work as expected. Instead, the trick was to use:

```
a2ensite/a2dissite mysite  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Goal is simply to format the output as I wish, with `echo -e "\tWhatever message"` and keep the output clean and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to see any output from these commands. But you can simply redirect the output to /dev/null with

```
a2ensite ... > /dev/null
```